# Failure to install Ubuntu Linux

Tags: 14.04

My System: Intel 4930k processor, Sapphire(AMD) R9 270 4Gb video card, 32Gb GSkill memory, Samsung 250GB EVO SSD Single (Partition for Windows 7 Ultimate), Asus X79Gold MB, Seagate 1Tb disc drive with 2 logical partitions, Pioneer BDxl Bluray DVD and Asus DVD.

Problem: I tried to install Ubuntu 15.10 from ISO disc provided with *Linux Forum* magazine.  I got the black screen which I found out probably occurred due to incompatibility of the video driver (noted on notes on 15.10 on this site) for the R9 and the 4.3 kernel. I then tried to download the 14.04.3LTS version from this site and I get as far the screen asking where I would like to install Linux.  First I chose to repartition C:/ on the SSD.  This resulted in a "cannot load "metafi..." error.  I tried twice same error.  I presume it meant "cannot load metafile..." I then tried to install on the Seagate hard drive, same message.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get Linux to install?

Comment: Just to make sure: You aren't using wubi to install? Make sure you download an ISO image and burn that to a DVD and run it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS. Then follow the process to install Ubuntu. Rather than partitioning during the linux install one can very well partition it within Windows(if you are new to Linux) using Windows disk partition tool(under computer management). Make sure that you create some space for /boot on SSD and then install remaining Ubuntu Linux into the unused portion of your 1 TB hard drive. You can have both Ubuntu and Window on that 1 TB hard drive. You can very well use gparted to do partitioning in Linux if needed. Hope this helps.